# carrierwave_direct exception empty file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I use carrierwave_direct to upload a file , but when the uploaded file is empty I got such error:

```
<Error><Code>EntityTooSmall</Code><Message>Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size</Message><MinSizeAllowed>1</MinSizeAllowed><ProposedSize>0</ProposedSize><RequestId>FE2FE66371A06E29</RequestId><HostId>k3aJ8EtnmPvVxJszZukKYbtEO5Ddrjq/a+FdhqTyL1nZ7afy+msTAA1MiwX8lXvH</HostId></Error>
```

How to catch this exception??
My code:

```
collection_action :new_import do
    @uploader = @organization.import_file
    @organization.save
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = import_admin_organization_rooms_url(@organization)
  end

  collection_action :import do
    RoomImportWorker.perform_async(params[:bucket],params[:key],@organization.id,current_user.id)
    redirect_to admin_organization_rooms_path(@organization), :notice => "Your request has been accepted! We will inform you via email about the results!"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This validation looks good i guess:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size